# How to disable internal types replacement with module path in sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Should be easy to fix, but i cannot find any glue anywhere ho to avoid sphinx  to change annotation in source code:

```
def load(self, fname: string = None) -> None:
```

to this in generated documentation:

```
load(fname: <module 'string' from 'C:\\Users\\jsakalos\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\string.py'> = None) → None¶
```

I would like to keep internal types untouched.

Comment: do you really mean the `string`-module, or the internal `str` type?

Comment: @Maarten: You are right, that fixed my issue. Please create answer so i can mark it as correct.
Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant

```
def load(self, fname: str = None) -> None:
```

The `fname` is probably a s`str` and not an instance of the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html) builtin module

PS. I use `pathlib.Path` for file handling